# Conditions that make volume of function rotated around $x$- axis finite

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help on this question:
Let $f(x)$ be a monotonically decreasing positive function with $y$-intercept $1.$ Which of the following guarantees the volume of the region bounded by rotating $f(x)$ about the $x$-axis is finite?

I. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)< \infty$

II. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (f(n))^2< \infty$

III. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (f(n))^3< \infty$

I know that we are trying to find the conditions that guarantee $\pi \int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x))^2dx=\pi\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n^2} (f(i/n))^ 2 < \infty$ and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n^2} (f(i/n))^ 2 <\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n^2} (f(i/n))^ 2 < \infty$. But I am stuck from here. I was thinking maybe proving that the conditions are less than  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n^2} (f(i/n))^ 2$? But I am stuck on how to do that. Please help!

Comment: Please type your question instead of posting a link.

Answer (score 0):

We want that the integral 
$$V = \pi \int\limits_0^{+\infty}f^2 (x)\ dx$$  converges.

Note that $f$ is a positive decreasing function, and thus so does $f^2$ .

Hence the integral $V$ and the series

$$\sum f^2 (n)$$ have the same nature.

So we need that the last series to be convergent.

Observe that if $\sum f (n) $ converges, then $f (n)\to 0$ when $n\to +\infty $, and for large enough $n $,
$$0\le f^2 (n)\le f (n)<1$$
thus $\sum f^2 (n) $ will also converge.

Answer. : $I $ and $II $.

Comment: The answer key says that the answer is I and II. Can you explain why I also needs to converge?

Comment: @ChrisNguyen By comparison test.